# Error when reading avro files in python

Tags: python-3.x, avro

I installed Apache Avro successfully in Python. Then I try to read Avro files into Python following the instruction below.

```
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedpython.html
```

I have a bunch of Avros in a directory which has already been set as the right path in Python. Here is my code:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = DataFileReader(open("part-00000-of-01733.avro", "r"), DatumReader())
for user in reader:
   print (user)
reader.close()
```

However it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\DJ data\read avro.py", line 5, in <module>
    reader = DataFileReader(open("part-00000-of-01733.avro", "r"), DatumReader())
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\datafile.py", line 349, in __init__
    self._read_header()
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\datafile.py", line 459, in _read_header
    META_SCHEMA, META_SCHEMA, self.raw_decoder)
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 525, in read_data
    return self.read_record(writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg \avro\io.py", line 725, in read_record
    field_val = self.read_data(field.type, readers_field.type, decoder)
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 515, in read_data
    return self.read_fixed(writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 568, in read_fixed
    return decoder.read(writer_schema.size)
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 170, in read
    input_bytes = self.reader.read(n)
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 863: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am indeed aware that in the example in the instruction, a schema is created first. But what is a avsc file? How shall I create it and the corresponding schema in my case? **Ideally, I would like to read Avro files into Python and save it into csv format in the disk or dataframe/list type in Python for further analysis.** I'm using Python 3 on Windows 7.

**EDITED**
I tried Stephane's code, and it returns a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\DJ data\read avro.py", line 5, in <module>
    reader = DataFileReader(open("part-00000-of-01733.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
  File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\datafile.py", line 352, in __init__
    self.codec = self.GetMeta('avro.codec').decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

**EDITED2**: Stephane's code works in most cases, but sometimes it incurs AssertionError like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "I:\DJ data\read avro.py", line 42, in <module>
for user in reader:
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\datafile.py", line 522, in __next__
datum = self.datum_reader.read(self.datum_decoder)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 480, in read
return self.read_data(self.writer_schema, self.reader_schema, decoder)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 525, in read_data
return self.read_record(writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 725, in read_record
field_val = self.read_data(field.type, readers_field.type, decoder)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 523, in read_data
return self.read_union(writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 689, in read_union
return self.read_data(selected_writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 493, in read_data
return self.read_data(writer_schema, s, decoder)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 503, in read_data
return decoder.read_utf8()
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 248, in read_utf8
input_bytes = self.read_bytes()
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 241, in read_bytes
return self.read(nbytes)
File "I:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg\avro\io.py", line 171, in read
assert (len(input_bytes) == n), input_bytes
AssertionError: b'BlackRock Group\n\n17 December 2015\n\nFORM 8.3\n\nPUBLIC OPENING POSITION DISCLOSURE/DEALING DISCLOSURE BY\n\nA PERSON WITH INTERESTS IN RELEVANT SECURITIES REPRESENTING 1% OR MORE\n\nRule 8.3 of the Takeover Code (the "Code") \n\n\n   1.         KEY INFORMATION \n \n (a) Full name of discloser:                                                                        BlackRock, Inc. \n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ----------------- \n (b) Owner or controller of interests and short positions disclosed, if diffe
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using windows and Python 3.

- in Python 3 by default `open` opens files in text mode. It means that when further read operations happen, Python will try to decode the content of the file from some charset to unicode.
- you did not specify a default charset, so Python tries to decode the content as if such content was encoded using `charmap` (by default on windows).
- obviously your avro file is not encoded in charmap, and the decoded fails with an exception
- as far as i remember, avro headers anyway are binary content... not textual (not sure about that). so maybe first you should try NOT to decode the file with open:

`reader = DataFileReader(open("part-00000-of-01733.avro", 'rb'), DatumReader())`

(notice `'rb'`, binary mode)

EDIT: For the next problem (AttributeError), you've been hit by a known bug that's not fixed in 1.8.1. Until next version is out, you could just do something like:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter, VALID_CODECS, SCHEMA_KEY
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
from avro import io as avro_io


class MyDataFileReader(DataFileReader):
    def __init__(self, reader, datum_reader):
        """Initializes a new data file reader.

        Args:
          reader: Open file to read from.
          datum_reader: Avro datum reader.
        """
        self._reader = reader
        self._raw_decoder = avro_io.BinaryDecoder(reader)
        self._datum_decoder = None  # Maybe reset at every block.
        self._datum_reader = datum_reader

        # read the header: magic, meta, sync
        self._read_header()

        # ensure codec is valid
        avro_codec_raw = self.GetMeta('avro.codec')
        if avro_codec_raw is None:
            self.codec = "null"
        else:
            self.codec = avro_codec_raw.decode('utf-8')
        if self.codec not in VALID_CODECS:
            raise DataFileException('Unknown codec: %s.' % self.codec)

        self._file_length = self._GetInputFileLength()

        # get ready to read
        self._block_count = 0
        self.datum_reader.writer_schema = (
            schema.Parse(self.GetMeta(SCHEMA_KEY).decode('utf-8')))


reader = MyDataFileReader(open("part-00000-of-01733.avro", "r"), DatumReader())
for user in reader:
    print (user)
reader.close()
```

It is very strange that such stupid bug could go to releases though, and that's not a sign a code maturity!

Comment: I tried your code, but it returns new error. Please see the edited part in the question. Thanks.

Comment: well, it looks like the avro file does not explicity specify a codec in the header. if no codec is present, the spec says it should be 'null'. strangely the implementation does not seem to know.

Comment: there you are: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1741. the patch was not merged in avro python3 1.8.1 it seems.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it seems that the code has some errors. I guess in python 3, we should use "rb" instead of "r" when using open, right? And in the class block, it shows "avro_io" and "VALID_CODECS" are not defined. How to fix that?

Comment: yes 'rb'. for the undefined symbols, i added the required imports.

Comment: Awesome, it works! But how can I convert reader into other types? like string. since I need to parse the text further. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hi, it seems it has other issues when reading the Avro files, could you please take a look at the edited question?